# Using insertText to edit a google form response on google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a form that stores responses in a google sheet and what I'm trying to do is on form submit, I want to add or insert a text to a column to turn the response to a hyperlink. For example the response is **123456**, I need to convert it to *https://www.google.com/123456*. I currently have this script but I'm getting an error on the insertText part.

```
var hyperlink = 'https://www.google.com/' 

function onformsubmit(e){

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');

var rg = sheet.getRange(1,3,sheet.getLastRow(),1);
var data = rg.getValues();

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  var datstr=String(data[i][0]).insertText(0,hyperlink);
  data[i][0]= (datstr);
}

rg.setValues(data);
}
```

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the insert part I think what you want is this code in the for-loop:

```
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
  data[i][0] = hyperlink + data[i][0];
}

rg.setValues(data);
```

That will change all text in that column to include the modified hyperlink. If you want to just modify the new row whenever you submit a form response you'll need to access the values or range from the event argument (e), using e.range, e.values, e.namedValues or probably some combination. See the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit).